# Animating multiple lights randomly?

Tags: lighting

Anybody have any idea of how to create some sort of master layout with all my lamps attached to their colors with for example nodes?

I would kind of want to be able to line them up in a vertical array add a color node to each of them that I can then have alternate between a specific section in the color spectrum and then randomise the animation with for example math nodes to make my scenes more dynamic during an animation.

I know I can link them but when linked all the colors are the same I want them all linked with nodes in such a way that how fast they "blink" or fade through the light frequencies is controlled from nodes that I can regulate myself so I don't have to go through them all one by one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127068/discussion-on-question-by-brecht-corbeel-animating-multiple-lights-randomly).